# Taleo extract process add blank field in output CSV file

Tags: extract, taleo, taleo-connect-client

I am using Taleo Connect Client to export data from Taleo. I encountered two questions:

1. How can I add blank columns to an output CSV file?

   For example, try to add `ColumnBlank1` between `Column_FirstName` and `Column_LastName`.

   ```
   Column_FirstName|ColumnBlank1|Column_LastName
   John||Lee
   Adam||Jackson
   ```
2. How can I set default value like "N" for one field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DBaluke Huang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47058788/3357935) was correct, but he left out some details.  Adding the full solution for others who might need this too.

To export a blank or fixed string value in a column using TCC (Taleo Connect client) do the following:

1. Open your Export
2. Click the projections tab
3. Click the add button
4. Click Projection Function
5. Choose the Replace Function
6. Click ok
7. In the First Parameter Section:  In the Value box, add any string field
   from your list on the entity tab. The Data Type should be Field.
8. In the Second Parameter Section, In the Value box, add the same field
   from Parameter 1 value box. The Data Type should be Field.
9. In the Third Parameter section, In the value box, enter no value for
   blank or enter the fixed string you want in all records.
10. Then change the data type to string in this section.

For those unfamiliar with the replace function you are looking for the string Parameter1.Value in Parameter2.value and then replacing all instances where the string is found with parameter3.value

Answer (score 0):

You can export a blank field with `<quer:string/>`.

```xml
<quer:projection alias="Blank" xmlns:quer="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/query">
  <quer:string/>
</quer:projection>
```

---

#### Steps

1. Open your export in Taleo Connect Client.
2. Open the *General* tab and set the *Export mode* to "CSV-report".
3. Open the *Projections* tab.
4. Click *Add*.
5. Select *Add a complex projection* and click *OK*.
6. Under *Complex projection*, enter the following:

   ```xml
   <quer:projection alias="Blank" xmlns:quer="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/query">
     <quer:string/>
   </quer:projection>
   ```
7. Save your changes.

#### Example:

```xml
<quer:query productCode="RC1704" model="http://www.taleo.com/ws/tee800/2009/01" projectedClass="Candidate" locale="en" mode="CSV" csvheader="true" csvdelimiter="|" largegraph="true" preventDuplicates="false" xmlns:quer="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/query">
  <quer:subQueries/>
  <quer:projections>
    <quer:projection>
      <quer:field path="FirstName"/>
    </quer:projection>
    <quer:projection alias="Blank">
      <quer:string/>
    </quer:projection>
    <quer:projection>
      <quer:field path="LastName"/>
    </quer:projection>
  </quer:projections>
  <quer:projectionFilterings/>
  <quer:filterings/>
  <quer:sortings/>
  <quer:sortingFilterings/>
  <quer:groupings/>
  <quer:joinings/>
</quer:query>
```

Results:

```xml
FirstName|Blank|LastName
John||Lee
Adam||Jackson
Jane||Doe
```

**Notes**:

- If you get a SAX parsing error when running the export, make sure your Export mode is set to "CSV-report". (Appears as `mode="CSV"` in source)
- When adding a complex projection in TCC, you *must* include `xmlns:quer="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/query"`, or else TCC will call your source "invalid". However, it is not required when editing your export's source directly outside of TCC.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved the issue by:

1. Add a function projection in Projections. Set your Alias. Set First parameter value as whatever field that available. Set the second parameter's value as same as the first parameter. Change Third parameter's value as "blank" and set Data type as String.
2. Same step as the first question, and set Change Third parameter's value as "N".